# maven deployable jar "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" error

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I have a deployable maven project where I'm trying to connect to a hive server using JDBC. This is my pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This generates a jar file which has a manifest.mf which is like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: test
Class-Path: hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar hive-common-2.1.1.jar ...
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_72
Main-Class: com.test.Main
```

Now, when I try to run the jar file using `java -jar test.jar`, I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

Why do I get this exception even though the jar file is configured properly in the classpath of the manifest file?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the dependencies next to the test.jar ?

Answer (score 2):

The jar referenced in the dependency seems not to be found by java. Probably is not located in the same folder as the target jar.

Depending on what you mean by deploayable maven project you have a couple of possible solutions

- add the dependency to the classpath of the container
- build a "fat" jar containing the dependency (using the maven shade or assembly plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy your dependencies from local or remote repositories to a specified location

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

or as another option use `maven-assembly-plugin` 
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure  which jar (hive ) do you want .. because it has diferent versions
The old verison jar is

`org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

here is the [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-jdbc/0.7.1-cdh3u6)

and the newest jar  is `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`  here is the new [settings](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/1.1.0-cdh5.13.1)

your mistakes is used the old dependency  with the new  jar name;